# How can create a dynamic list of json object (array)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm implementing a visual calendar (not CRUD) for an internal dashboard on my site.

I chose to use Brospars "Simple Calendar" jquery plugin.

Here the github link: https://github.com/brospars/simple-calendar

It all works, in theory. Because I couldn't figure out how to dynamically provide him with information about events.

The info is recorded on my DB like this:

- Date
- Now
- Event name

and they are multiple and different for each user.

So I create an array that sequentially contains these 3 items, but then I don't know how to insert them in the events line, I should create a loop that for each row of the array compiles me a list in json.

```
Event: {
      startDate: new Date(data+'T'+hour),
      endDate: new Date(data+'T'+hour),
      summary:'Appointment with con '+name event
    },
```

But this for each event line ... how can I make this work?

I am on wordpress and I am working with both php to extract the data from the db and with jquery to use the calendar.

Comment: Refere to the doc. **$calendar.addEvent(Event)** So yes you will need a loop

Comment: You should search for using JQuery as inline script in wordpress and your result from your query should be json_encoded see: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php
You can do a print_r(e.g. $data) and you see the array as a json string.

Comment: `events: [],` is array. SO you should use for each loop